# Understanding the learned weight for MNIST in TensorFlow

Tags: image-processing, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, deep-learning, mnist

I am trying to understand the [TensorFlow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html) which uses MNIST.

I would like to quote the following section:

> To tally up the evidence that a given image is in a particular class,
>   we do a weighted sum of the pixel intensities. The weight is negative
>   if that pixel having a high intensity is evidence against the image
>   being in that class, and positive if it is evidence in favor.
>
> The following diagram shows the weights one model learned for each of
>   these classes. Red represents negative weights, while blue represents
>   positive weights.
>
> [image]

**My question:**

Let's take the case of the class 0. So, what does the blue ring mean? The tutorial says blue means 'positive if it is evidence in favor'. What image are we talking about? All or a particular one from the training set? Moreover, what does the red blob in the center mean? Is this a given image? I don't understand what kind of code would generate this image for 0.

Answer (score 2):

If you read further in the tutorial you can see that the equation is written out in matrix format.

```
y (the label) = softmax (W^T x + b)
```

W represents a matrix of weights applied to each pixel, and b represents a number we add to each of the W^T x so it is an elementwise sum.  So once we have a trained model W and b are fixed.

We can them solve for what kind of input (x) will give us the highest value for a specific label.  So let y = [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] (i.e. the label representing the number 0).

```
softmax^(-1)(y) = W^T x + b

softmax^(-1)(y) - b =  W^T x

W^-T(softmax^(-1)(y) - b) = x
```

where softmax^(-1) represents the inverse of the softmax function.

This x is the input that would give us the highest value for a particular class in this case 0.  We can repeat the process for the other number by changing the vector y appropriately.

We can also plot this x (as it has the same dimensions as our input image and as is shown in your question). We plot it such that negative values are red, values close to 0 are black and positive values are blue.

Comment: which quantity are you talking about when you said 'highest value for a specific label'? Moreover, Where do we get the value of W^T from?

Comment: By highest value I mean the image such that if passed in you'll get the y that I defined. W^T is just some matrix of weights (i.e. a matrix of numbers) that is usually randomly initialized. If you continue reading the tutorial you'll see how to "train" W and b such that after some time it'll converge to some set of fixed values.

Comment: I am trying to understand the equation for evidence for class i given an input x. evidence_i = sum_j W_{i, j} x_j + b_i. So, does it mean as follows? We have a trained neural network. The weights of the network is encoded as the matrix W. Moreover, what is input x? Which of training, test or validation sets, does x belong to?

Comment: So there are two different things happening. One is how they generated the images which is what I described in my answer.  The second which you're asking now is given a new image (x) what is the evidence for a class.  Lastly x can come from any distribution train, val or test.  In any of them after calculating the softmax(W^T x + b) we have ten numbers in the range of [0,1] and we consider each number a probability. Hence why they use the word evidence for because a probability can be reinterpreted as evidence for a certain class. Hope that helps.

Comment: does it mean that the those ten images are the visualizations of the W matrices one for each digit?

Comment: No it's the visualization of my final equation that I derived above. W^-T(softmax^(-1)(y) - b) which takes on the same shape as an image so it can be viewed as one.

Comment: I think I should have asked these earlier. 1) What does $W^T$ mean?  Does it mean W transposed? 2) Quoting you "We can them solve for what kind of input (x) will give us the highest value for a specific label." - which of y and x you want to get the highest value for?